# Visual Studio 2017 VB.NET Forms App - saving project files to different locations

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have an older VB.NET Windows Forms App that was on an older laptop (Win7 Pro) that crashed that I need to move to a new laptop (Win10 Home).  Unfortunately when this project was created (*using Visual Studio 2017*) it had 4 project files that were somehow saved on the desktop (Form1.vb, Form1.Designer.vb, Form1.resx, and ApplicationEvents.vb).  I really want to get all of the project files together into a single folder (under "Visual Studio 2017\Projects").  After some tinkering I was able to get the project files moved over to the new machine but I had to put the 4 files back onto the desktop to allow it to compile.  I'll admit, I'm a little rusty on my VS use, so I'm not exactly sure how to move these desktop files within the project successfully.  I tried just doing a Save-As to a new path but I got build errors.  Can anyone provide a little help on how I can properly do this.  Appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move the files into the desired folder, and then remove the file references from the project and add them back from the new location. Or, if you're adventurous, you can do this by manually editing the dot-.vbproj file (which in your case should be called NSMConvertCSV.vbproj), which is XML.

The XML structure is pretty simple:

```
 <ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="Form1.vb">
     <SubType>Form</SubType>
   </Compile>
   <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.vb">
     <DependentUpon>Form1.vb</DependentUpon>
     <SubType>Form</SubType>
   </Compile>
   <Compile Include="My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb" />
   <Compile Include="My Project\Application.Designer.vb">
     <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
     <DependentUpon>Application.myapp</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
   <Compile Include="My Project\Resources.Designer.vb">
     <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
     <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
     <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
   <Compile Include="My Project\Settings.Designer.vb">
     <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
     <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
     <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
   </Compile>
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
     <DependentUpon>Form1.vb</DependentUpon>
   </EmbeddedResource>
   <EmbeddedResource Include="My Project\Resources.resx">
     <Generator>VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
     <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
     <CustomToolNamespace>My.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
     <SubType>Designer</SubType>
   </EmbeddedResource>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I remove the file references from the project and add them back in?

And where do I find that XML file?  The name of the VS solution file is NSMConvertCSV and I searched within the "Visual Studio\Projects\NSMConvertCSV" folder and there are only 2 .xml files; NSMConvertCSV.xml & NSMConvertCSV.TrustInfo.xml.  Neither of which contain any file or path info.  If I directly update the XML file you reference, that will not cause any issues with the project in other ways, correct?

Comment: The dot-VBPROJ file should be called NSMConvertCSV.vbproj. To be safe, you can back up the VBPROJ in case you make an unrecoverable mistake.

Comment: To remove a file from the solution, right-click the file in Solution Explorer and select 'Exclude from Project.' To add it back in from the correct location, right-click the project in Solution Explorer, select 'Add', then 'Existing Item,' and then choose the file in the new location.

Comment: Ok, I backed up the VBPROJ XML file and tried to get it to compile.  I had a "My Project" folder already configured in the project, so I just moved the 4 files into that directory and updated the XML lines for those files accordingly.  The Solution Explorer did show everything included properly when I opened VS.  I started a Debug session to see if it would compile but I get BC2001 error, stating it can't find "C:\Users\xx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\NSMConvertCSV\NSMConvertCSV\My Project\Desktop\Form1.vb".  Not sure why it's still looking for this on the Desktop.

Comment: "My Project" is for global settings and resources. You should have the form source files in <base>\NSMConvertCSV\NSMConvertCSV, not <base>\NSMConvertCSV\NSMConvertCSV\My Project.

Comment: This project has some oddities in the file structure.  And I'm not remembering the details.  I'd like to get this cleaned up while I'm addressing this Desktop file problem.  Not sure if you can help me with this.  Appreciate it if you could.  First, there are 2 Form1.vb files, the one that was on the Desktop, and that has the current code.  The other one has an earlier version of the code and really can be deleted. And the Form1.vb file has my frmNCC class which contains all the code for my application.  I probably should rename this to frmNCC.vb.

Comment: Rename the earlier Form1.vb and its companion  Form1.Designer.vb and Form1.resx files (for safekeeping). Then, copy in the files from the desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to get it to compile. I made a mistake in one of the file paths in the XML file. I also deleted the obsolete Form1.vb file with no impacts. However, it's not happy when I try to rename the Form1.vb file.

Comment: The other issue I now have is that I appear to have lost the [Design] version of my Form1.  I can compile it fine.  And I have the Form1.Designer.vb and all of the associated control definitions.  But I don't appear to have the Form1.vb [Design] view of the Form1.  The Form1 icon shown in the Solution Explorer is just dashed tabbed rectangle.  Versus the normal form icon.  BYTW, is there a legend anywhere that shows exactly what the icons in the Solution Explorer actually mean?? When I click it, it just takes me to the class code definition.

Comment: You need to copy over the Form1.Designer.vb and Form1.resx files as well.

Comment: They have been copied.

Comment: All three of those files (i.e. Form1.vb, Form1.Designer.vb and Form1.resx) were already copied.  As I stated, I can open Form1.Designer.vb and see all of the code for the form controls within the Partial Class frmNCC but I can't access the form itself like you normally would.  I can't visually manipulate the controls but I can adjust properties by making changes to the code directly in the Form1.Designer.vb file.

Comment: Any idea why I can only see the code version of the form??

Comment: The designer file is not properly attached? Click the 'show all files' button to show all the files in the hierarchy.